# How do I make the script to run automatically when tun0 interface up/down events?

Tags: internet, networking, interface, ifconfig

I use VPN client to connect to my corporate servers. It creates tun0 interface after starting the client. I've written script which install specific routes point to tun0 interface and rest to use normal wifi connection. So that, only my office related traffic goes via VPN and rest are goes via home internet connection. How do I make the script to run automatically when tun0 interface up/down events ?.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am not sure about `tun0`, but I think the script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and `/etc/network/if-down.d/` are invoked when an interface goes up or down, respectively.

Inside the script you can determine which interface is interested from the content of the variable `IFACE`.

To be sure, add a simple script to `/etc/network/if-up.d/` which content is

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: tun-up

if [ "$IFACE" = tun0 ]; then
  echo "tun0 up" >> /var/log/tun-up.log
fi
```

make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/tun-up
```

then see if the up events are recorded in `/var/log/tun-up.log`

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting below syslog message and the scripts are not invoked at all. /etc/network/interfaces has no info other than loopback. 

May  9 15:26:48 mypc NetworkManager[869]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ubuntu 20, and I even copy/pasted your code. Has this behavior changed in recent Ubuntus?

Comment: This answer is outdated, not working on ubuntu20.

Answer (score 12):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add:

```
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet manual
    up COMMAND
```

`COMMAND` can be a command, like `ip route add something...` or a script path with executable permissions (`chmod +x`), eventually stored in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`.

Instead of `up` you may use `post-up`, `down`, `post-down`.

[Documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html):

> IFACE OPTIONS
>
> ```
>    The  following  "command"  options  are  available for every family and
>    method.  Each of these options can be given multiple times in a  single
>    stanza,  in  which case the commands are executed in the order in which
>    they appear in the stanza.  (You can ensure a command  never  fails  by
>    suffixing them with "|| true".)
>
>    pre-up command
>           Run  command  before bringing the interface up.  If this command
>           fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
>           configured,  prints  an  error message, and exits with status 0.
>           This behavior may change in the future.
>
>    up command
>
>    post-up command
>           Run command after bringing the interface up.   If  this  command
>           fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
>           configured (even though it has really been  configured),  prints
>           an  error  message,  and exits with status 0.  This behavior may
>           change in the future.
>
>    down command
>
>    pre-down command
>           Run command before taking the interface down.  If  this  command
>           fails  then  ifdown  aborts, marks the interface as deconfigured
>           (even though it has not really  been  deconfigured),  and  exits
>           with status 0.  This behavior may change in the future.
>
>    post-down command
>           Run  command  after  taking the interface down.  If this command
>           fails then ifdown aborts, marks the interface  as  deconfigured,
>           and  exits  with  status  0.   This  behavior  may change in the
>           future.
>
>    There exists for each  of  the  above  mentioned  options  a  directory
>    /etc/network/if-<option>.d/  the  scripts  in  which  are  run (with no
>    arguments)  using  run-parts(8)  after  the  option  itself  has   been
>    processed.  Please  note  that  as post-up and pre-down are aliases, no
>    files in the corresponding directories are processed.  Please  use  if-
>    up.d and if-down.d directories instead.
>
>    All  of  these  commands  have  access  to  the  following  environment
>    variables.
>
>    IFACE  physical name of the interface being processed
>
>    LOGICAL
>           logical name of the interface being processed
>
>    ADDRFAM
>           address family of the interface
>
>    METHOD method of the interface (e.g., static)
>
>    MODE   start if run from ifup, stop if run from ifdown
>
>    PHASE  as per MODE, but with finer granularity, distinguishing the pre-
>           up, post-up, pre-down and post-down phases.
>
>    VERBOSITY
>           indicates whether --verbose was used; set to 1 if so, 0 if not.
>
>    PATH   the   command   search   path:  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:���
>           /usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>
>    Additionally, all options given in an interface definition  stanza  are
>    exported to the environment in upper case with "IF_" prepended and with
>    hyphens  converted  to  underscores  and  non-alphanumeric   characters
>    discarded.
>
>    When  ifupdown  is  being  called  with  the --all option, before doing
>    anything to interfaces, if calls all the hook scripts (pre-up or  down)
>    with  IFACE set to "--all", LOGICAL set to the current value of --allow
>    parameter  (or  "auto"   if   it's   not   set),   ADDRFAM="meta"   and
>    METHOD="none".   After all the interfaces have been brought up or taken
>    down, the appropriate scripts (up or post-down) are executed.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I've used `systemd` to run a script after `network-online.target`.
My script `<path>/script.sh`.

1.) `sudo systemctl edit --force --full my-script.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script after network available
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=<path>/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2.) `sudo systemctl enable my-script.service`

3.) `sudo systemctl start my-script.service`