# Prevent automatic updates on certain WiFi networks

Tags: wireless, unattended-upgrades

I have a 200 MB / month plan on my cell phone and automatic updates on my Ubuntu machine. That works just fine, unless I tether them together. A couple days ago, something, I presume automatic updates, used all of it, leaving me nothing for the rest of the month.

Is there a possibility to prevent automatic updates on certain WiFi networks?

### Related

- [Is it possible to disable the automatic download of updates when the internet connection is through a 3G dongle?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72602/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-automatic-download-of-updates-when-the-internet-co)

Comment: probably much easier to turn off automatic updates entirely and then just use the update manager when you have wifi.